# Swap words within email address

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have the following "incorrect" email addresses that needs to be rearranged:

- com@user1234.google
- com@user4321.yahoo
- com@user5555.outlook

I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
sed -r 's/(^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-][^@]*) \(@[A-Za-z0-9.-][^.]*) \([.][A-Za-z0-9.-]*)/\3 \2 \1/'
```

Comment: Needs to be rearranged in this format: user1234@google.com

Comment: Thanks Scott for the reformat of the question... I apologize for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/\([^@]*\)@\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\)/\2@\3.\1/' file
user1234@google.com
user4321@yahoo.com
user5555@outlook.com
```

Comment: You know I spent close to 3 hours on this!!! Freddy!!! YOU ROCK!!! It worked

Answer (score 1):

Awk is often a good choice for delimited data ex.

```
$ awk -F'[@.]' '{print $2 "@" $3 "." $1}' file
user1234@google.com
user4321@yahoo.com
user5555@outlook.com
```